# if empty fields from a form exclude from URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've tried some of the suggestions in other answers but cant find one that works for me.
This is the problem I have:

```
<form method="get">
<input name="field1">
<input name="field2">
<input type="submit" name="field1">
<form>
```

If  only enter a value in field one I get this in the URL:

```
mysite.com?field1=this&field2
```

what I need is this:

```
mysite.com?field1=this
```

I whant it to be a clean simple javascript line of code NO jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Javascript when your form is submitted (via the [`onsubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit) event) to iterate through the `<input>` elements within your form that do not have a value and then disable them (as disabled elements will not be posted to the server) :

```
<form method="get" onsubmit='cleanUpEmptyElements(this);'>
   <input name="field1">
   <input name="field2">
   <input type="submit" name="field1">
<form>
<script> 
   // When your form is submitted
   function cleanUpEmptyElements(element){
       // Iterate through the available <input> elements
       var inputs = element.getElementsByTagName("input");
       for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            // Disable those that do not have a value
            if(inputs[i].value.length == 0 && inputs[i].type != 'submit') {
                inputs[i].disabled = 'disabled';
            }
       }  
       // Continue your submission as normal
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Very clean example here I like it, +1 for using disabled

Comment: sorry my friend,  the empty field keeps appearing on the url.

Comment: Hmmm. You could try explicitly removing it from the DOM using `element.removeChild(inputs[i]);` or try removing the `name` attribute using `inputs[i].name = '';`. within your loop.

Comment: Sorry non worked... I gess Ill have to figure it out on the php side of things.
Thank You for your help.

Comment: Additionally try removing the `name` attribute from your submit button to see if that helps. It might cause some confusion with your other element with the same attribute.